# Loading specific layer by its name from GeoPackage

Tags: qgis, layers, geopackage, ppygis

How can I load a specific layer by its name from a GeoPackage into the project. I tried the graphical model designer, but it always loads a layer from the geopackage and labels it with my layer name (in this case Proejct_Layername_in_Layertree). I do not know where to set this.

```
[...]
class DatenInProjektLaden(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        pass

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
        # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
        # overall progress through the model
        feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(1, model_feedback)
        results = {}
        outputs = {}

        # Load Layer into Project
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': 'C:/Users/../../../...gpkg',
            'NAME': 'Proejct_Layername_in_Layertree'
        }
        outputs['LoadLayerIntoProject'] = processing.run('native:loadlayer', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        return results

[...]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add to the INPUT path "|layername" so | and the name of the layer in the GeoPackage and it open the correct one

```
[...]

class DatenInProjektLaden(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        pass

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
        # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
        # overall progress through the model
        feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(1, model_feedback)
        results = {}
        outputs = {}

        # Load Layer into Project
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': 'C:/Users/../../../...gpkg|layername = nameoftheyouwant',
            'NAME': 'Proejct_Layername_in_Layertree'
        }
        outputs['LoadLayerIntoProject'] = processing.run('native:loadlayer', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        return results

',
            'NAME': 'Proejct_Layername_in_Layertree'
        }
        outputs['LoadLayerIntoProject'] = processing.run('native:loadlayer', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        return results
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand what you want to do...You could try this after # Load Layer into project.  It asks for a parameter which is the full path to the geopackage and includes the layername e.g.

'C:\myfolder\mygeopackagename.gpkg|layername=mylayername'.
Then it uses the layername in the geopackage for the layername in the project

` # Load layer into project

```
    alg_params = {
        'INPUT': parameters['LayerNametoLoad'],
        'NAME': QgsExpression('\r\nright(@LayerNametoLoad,length(@LayerNametoLoad) - (strpos( @LayerNametoLoad ,\'.gpkg|layername=\') + 15))\r\n').evaluate()
    }`
```

Here is the expression in the modeller:

right(@LayerNametoLoad,length(@LayerNametoLoad) - (strpos( @LayerNametoLoad ,'.gpkg|layername=') + 15))

This is the graphical modeler setup:
[image]

Comment: that did not work for me but I got an idea with the part "|layername"